# Delete rows from dataframe based on column value in R

Tags: r, dataframe

```
Sample_ID<-c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6")
Heart_attack<-c("1", "0", "1", "1", "0", "2")
DF<-data.frame(Sample_ID,Heart_attack)
```

I want to exclude from my data frame, all the samples having "0" in Heart_attack.How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you do `str(DF)` you will see that `Heart_attack` is of type factor. Therefore you need to drop the `0` level:

```
df2 <- droplevels(DF[-which(DF$Heart_attack == "0"), ])
df2
  Sample_ID Heart_attack
1        a1            1
3        a3            1
4        a4            1
6        a6            2
```

To check whether the `0`level really has disappeared, you can use `table`:

```
table(df2$Heart_attack)
1 2 
3 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
  DF <- DF %>% 
  filter(Heart_attack != 0) %>% 
  droplevels()
```

Comment: The level `0`is still there even after the `subset` operation. Check out `table(DF)`(after the subset): `table(DF$Heart_attack)
0 1 2 
0 3 1` This goes for both the `base R` and the `dplyr` solution!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that. Updated the `dplyr` solution with  `droplevels()`

Answer (score 0):

An option with `subset` from `base R`

```
df2 <-  droplevels(subset(DF, as.logical(as.integer(Heart_attack))))
```